# Aspx.net to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Hi I am trying to convert the current running aspx page to pdf. I tried many code but its not working. One of them is -

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


panel1.RenderControl(hw);
panel2.RenderControl(hw);            
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

If I add each panel it is coming but still some of the data into the panel like table content is not there in pdf. I even tried - `this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

But it shows error : RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render()

So Please suggest the way I can achieve it.

Comment: After taking a brief look at the PdfWriter library on CodePlex it doesn't look like it supports the conversion of HTML to PDF (happy to be wrong here). The only examples that I saw where the building up of a PDF document using the PdfWriter library.

In the source that you posted it is unclear what "panel1" and "panel2" are but I am guessing that they are ASP.NET controls which would explain the error that you are seeing. The error is coming from the ASP.NET controls not the PdfWriter library.

Comment: You really, really shouldn't use `HTMLWorker`, it is deprecated. Use `XMLWorker` instead, and use that as a keyword to search in the official documentation on http://developers.itextpdf.com, and you will find many examples. What @RyanPedersen wrote about iText, is incorrect. What he wrote about the error, is probably correct.

Comment: When using XMLWorker it shows error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.